# Create a GCP Kubernetes Cluster from existing config?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, tagcloud

I have a GKE cluster.. I'd like to download this config and keep it in my local repository so that I may later recreate this in other projects/environments.

Is there a way to do this?

I was able to get the yaml by running:
gcloud container clusters describe standard-cluster-1 --region=us-central1

But not quite sure how I can use this to create a new cluster in a different environment

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to directly fetch the configuration from an already-created cluster.

However, if you use Cloud Console and click on "Create a new cluster", on your left hand side of the page, you can see an option called "Clone an existing cluster". Afterwards, you can find the "Equivalent REST or command line" options at the bottom.

Keep in mind however that this system isn't flawless and cloning an existing clusters might improperly carry over networking and/or disk configuration so I would definitively recommend to do a few test runs to make sure everything is correct.